# Dividing the array in K parts

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamic-programming

Let the array $A$ of seven elements be defined:
\begin{align*}
 A[0] &= 2\\
  A[1] &= 1\\
  A[2] &= 5\\
  A[3] &= 1\\
  A[4] &= 2\\
  A[5] &= 2\\
  A[6] &= 2
\end{align*}
I have to divide the array into $K$ parts such that larger sum is low, and return the index of those $k$ parts. 
For example $k=3$
\begin{align*}
&[2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2],\, [],\, [] \quad\text{with a large sum of 15;}\\
&[2], [1, 5, 1, 2],\, [2, 2] \quad\ \ \ \text{with a large sum of 9;}\\
&[2, 1, 5],\, [], \,[1, 2, 2, 2] \quad\ \text{with a large sum of 8;}\\
&[2, 1],\, [5, 1],\, [2, 2, 2] \quad\ \ \ \text{with a large sum of 6.}
\end{align*}
So the algorithm should return 6. 
Which algorithm should I use ?
Please provide me with an approach or code.

Comment: how to use KMP for partitioning ?

Comment: i've edited now.
KMP is used for string matching problems.

Comment: You should say something about string matching algorithms in your question, and what methods/algorithms you've tried.